# Removal of personally identifying information

Tags: discussion, editing

Hear, hear:

There's now a new mod only editing tool redact that allows to remove personally identifying or login information from posts (as those things were previously still in the edit history). It requires two moderators, one to perform the edit and another one to approve.

So if you come across some ill-placed personal information, give the mods a ping to have it purged from the post.

See: [Allow moderators to hide a revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191121/allow-moderators-to-hide-a-revision/274274#274274)

Comment: Where did you see this it is news to me.

Comment: Teacher's Lounge, has been announced just last week.